# How to add Numeric Pager in Google Table Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

recently i am adding a Google table chart to my project. my task is to add a numeric pager in it. but i only can add

`options['pagingSymbols'] = {prev: 'prev', next: 'next'};
  options['pagingButtonsConfiguration'] = 'auto';`.

it only shows next and previous button. so how can i change it to numeric paging. thanks in advance.

Comment: If the answer below worked for you, please click the check mark below the up/down-vote arrows in the answer so that other people can see that this solved your issue. If my answer was not clear enough, or if you are still having issues, please add a comment to the answer explaining what that issue is/what isn't clear.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to create a custom event handler for your chart. For instance, you can use a dataView to get 10 rows of data as follows:

```
var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
var page = 1;
dataView.setRows(page * 10 - 9,page * 10);
```

You can then create buttons in any way you'd like (images, etc.) below the chart, and attach an event to each of them. You can have that event show the page number in between, and then when you click the < or > buttons, it will change the page and the number through a function call, such as:

```
page = page + 1; // Obviously -1 for the minus button
dataView.setRows(page * 10 - 9,page * 10);
```

Then you'd write the 'page' to your document where the page number exists. You can do a current/max page value by looking at the max rows of data using:

```
var maxPage = data.getNumberOfRows();
```

Then you can write some sort of an error trapping function (for if they click "back" on the first page, or try to move to "next" on the last page). Or you can grey out the buttons. Or you can have it loop to the last page. Or whatever.

Whenever you make a change, you just redraw the table using your dataView instead of the actual data.